# How to poll a remote json periodically using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The client reads remote json:

```
app.controller("StatusController", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Custom-Header"] = "Angular.js";
  $http.get('https://example.com/status.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.status = data;
    });

});
```

Currently the user refresh the status by reloading the webpage. How can I set up a timer (say, every 2 seconds) to polls the data and auto-refresh automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval):

```
app.controller("StatusController", function($scope, $http) {

  $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Custom-Header"] = "Angular.js";
  
  this.interval = setInterval(function(){$http.get('https://example.com/status.json').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.status = data;
    });}, 2000);
 
  this.endLongPolling = function(){ clearInterval(this.interval);};

});
```

`setInterval()` will continually execute the function you pass to it every interval delay, ( 2000 milliseconds === 2 seconds), until `clearInterval()` is called. In the example above I show how you can clear the interval in `endLongPolling`.

#### In fact the angular guys have already made a service for this; [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

```
$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply])
```

Applied to your scenario it would be:

```
app.controller("StatusController", function($scope, $http, $interval) {

  $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Custom-Header"] = "Angular.js";
  
  this.interval = $interval(function(){
    $http.get('https://example.com/status.json').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.status = data;
  });}, 2000);
 
  this.endLongPolling = function(){ $interval.cancel(this.interval);};

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution! All the other solutions I found were using a factory. I noticed though, that $http has internal caching active and was hindering me to do continuous updates. `$http.get('https://example.com/status.json', { cache: false})` solved this issue.